# How to deal with changing OData signatures in .NET DataServiceContext Service Reference

Tags: .net, odata, wcf-data-services, datacontext, service-reference

dear lovely community,

I need some help with .NET Service Reference stuff for OData services.
The webservices (Odata endpoints) for information download are located on container ships with different patchlevels for this data service.

[image: Service Reference]

I made a service reference to the current version of the service, but now there is a ship where one Property is missing. Of course i am getting an Exception when i try to access the Entity with missing property like this:
[image]

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred 
while processing this request. ---> 
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: <?xml version="1.0" 
encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code></code>
<message xml:lang="en-US">Type 'WebService.OData.EntityClasses.Container_E' does not have a property named 'Monitored'.</message>
</error> at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery() at  System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement] DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents)--- End of inner exception stack trace --- at 
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement]
(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

The IgnoreMissingProperties option on Context doesn't seem to help[image: context options]

So what can I do to ignore this property? If The property is not there I'm not interested in the value anymore, but I will not make different Implementations of the service manifest (interface).

I was trying an approach like this:[image]
IgnoredRefconProperties is a string[] -> in this case with one entry "Monitored"
But this doesn't seem to do anything.

Heeeelp :)